# How to take a screenshot while playing a HLS stream using AV foundation?

Tags: ios7, ios6, video-streaming, avfoundation, screenshot

I am playing a video in my app, the video is a HLS streaming which i am fetching from my remote server. And i need a functionaltiy to take the screenshot of currently playing video but i am not able to do the same, i checked the documentation apple is saying you can take the screenshot if you are playing a video if you are playing a video from LOCAL URL or LOCAL FILE and you can not take a screenshot if you are playing a video from remote stream.

I am kind of stuck on this issue, i tried several methods discussed on stack overflow and other sites but nothing worked.

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: is there anyone who can help one this ????

Comment: I'm running into the same issue on iOS7.